# Getting Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLocalVersion() for com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am getting Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLocalVersion() when I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0 & gradle-2.10 plugin.
Has anyone started using this? I want to try instant run feature.